# DNN 7 module moves every other module up

Tags: module, dotnetnuke

I'm running a local install of DNN in a development capacity. I have a "testimonials" module that I want to use. The problem I get is that when I drag into a pane it causes all modules above it to "shift" up to a point where they go behind a content slider I have. Tried various CSS methods to fix it but I can't seem to find the bug. Has anyone else experienced the issue before??

Also tried contacting the owner but his last activity was in 2012.

thanks

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="Testimonials.ascx.vb" Inherits="Ovionx.DNN.Testimonials.Testimonials" %>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlTestimonials" runat="server">
<div id="rotating_homepage_text">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTestimonials" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<div>
<%# FormatTestimonial(Container.DataItem) %>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
var currentTallest = 0;
var offsetPadding = 0;

$("#rotating_homepage_text")
<% If ShowPager Then %>
.before('<div id="rotating_homepage_text_nav">')
<% End If %>
.cycle({
    fx: 'turnUp',
    speed: <%= TransitionSpeed.ToString %>,
    speedIn: 100,
    speedOut: 100,
    pager: '#rotating_homepage_text_nav'
})
.children().each(function(){
    if ($(this).height() > currentTallest) {
        currentTallest = $(this).height();
    }
});

offsetPadding = $("#rotating_homepage_text").offset().top - $("#<%=pnlTestimonials.ClientID%>").offset().top;

$("#<%=pnlTestimonials.ClientID%>").css('height', (currentTallest + offsetPadding + 30) + 'px');
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: This is something that likely won't be able to be answered unless you put more details about what the modules are, and what the HTML code looks like that is causing the issue

Comment: hi Chris - Modules are standard HTML/Text Modules and Will Strohl content slider. As for code I can't see any positioning additions and the source looks clean

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might try is switching to the LAYOUT mode on the page and see if that allows you to position the modules on the page.

Layout mode "hides" the content itself, so you can work with the module/containers to move things around, where in Edit/View mode that can sometimes be more difficult to do.

You might ultimately need to modify the Content Slider module if it is positioning things wrong in HTML, that or customize your SKIN so that the slider is in a different Pane than all other modules.

Comment: Tried the layout mode and all the positioning is correct, once switched back to edit mode the modules shift up. It only happens once I add the testimonial module.

Comment: You might look at the ASCX for the Testimonial to see if it is doing something with a FLOAT or position in the CSS

Comment: Had a look and there is no float: have edited the above to include the code.

Comment: also checked the source again and there's position: absolute being added to all testimonials despite being unable to locate it in the source.

Comment: Is that in the HTML, or is that in the CSS? If in the CSS, you might be able to use a tool like Firebug to track down where it is coming from

Comment: Its in the HTML - can't see it anywhere in the modules code, wondering how its been generated

Comment: Is the page publicly accessible?